# Foreach Container to loop through Multiple Excel File to load

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have had Packages in the past where I was looping through multiple Text files in a folder and loading into sql server tables.

Now I am asked to create a package which will loop through Multiple Excel Files in a folder and load them into sql server table.

I went through the following steps to create this package assuming it shouldn't be much different from what I have in other packages where it loops through multiple Flat file.

1. Added an `Execute Sql Task`, Truncating my staging table, A simple Truncate table statement.
2. Added a `Foreach Loop Container`.  Selected `Foreach File Enumerator` and created a variable called `File_Path` with data type string.
   [image]
   [image]
3. Added a `Data Flow Task`.
4. Added an `Excel Data Source`. and configured the `Excel Connection manager` By selecting any one 'Excel' File in the destination folder. (At this point is configured correctly as it is not showing any red cross or warring messages.)
5. Then I selected the `Excel File Connection Manager` and in `Properties` windows Under `Expressions`, Selected `Connection String` property and Used the User Variable `@User::File_Path`.

[image]

At this point the Excel Data source is showing a `Red Cross` as it needs further configuration.

[image]

I have tried a few things Like changing the `Data Access Mode` from `Table name` to `Table Name or View Name Variable`, And passing variable `@User::File_Path` but it gives me the following error.

[image]

Can someone please have a look and advice where I am going wrong and how I can fix this? Any Advice or a pointer in the right direction is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: So you are storing password and not using windows authentication (as I see from your conn manager properties). Right?

Comment: I think it is using Windows Authentication as I havent changed any of the default settings.

Comment: Well, I am no SSIS pro but in the error msg (per your post), I don't see the specific error other than it's  hex error code. what's the error name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use an expression on the ConnectionString property, but on the **ExcelFilePath** property.

Comment: I did try this before but it didnt work as I forgot to set `DelayValidation` to true. Thanks for your help :)